# Dialogflow Nodejs catching wrong credentials error

Tags: node.js, promise, dialogflow-es

I want to catch the error from google auth when I typed in the wrong credentials. It just outputs Unhandeled Promised Rejection even though I try to catch the error.

My Code:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
async function listIntents(config){
    try{
        const intentClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient(config);
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("Error Caught")
    }

}
listIntents('dfdff');
```

Error Output:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hein\Desktop\telegram-bot-home\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:168:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Hein\Desktop\telegram-bot-home\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:19:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: With the exact code you posted, using node 10.15.1 and the dialogflow library version 0.8.2, I'm not getting any errors. I wouldn't expect that when the object is created, since the credentials aren't tested at this time. Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55558666/edit) to provide any more information about your environment or what else your code is doing?

Comment: Yeah there's no problem when I put in the right credentials. What I want to do is to test the credentials the user is providing so that I can provide them with a message that they are providing an incorrect one. I want to catch the reject provided in the question. I'm sorry if its confusing.

Comment: What you're trying to do makes sense. But the literal code that you posted, including the call to `listIntents()`, doesn't cause that error for me. Does that code itself cause the problem? If so, what is the rest of the environment you're using.